# Transfer Mistake between ERC20 vs ERC721

Tags: erc-721

I accidentally sent NFT to the ERC20 address on my ledger instead of ERC721; the wallet shows no transaction. Can I reclaim my NFT?

0x054138a3d3c7cc8925b163eafcdd60612b63425eb7e841034ed735a19a9bdc72

Answer (score 1):

If you check on etherscan (either via your address balance or the NFT contract's ownerOf function), the token has been transfered to your address and is there.

If you're using metamask with your Ledger, I'd suggest going to the NFT contract ["Write" page](https://etherscan.io/token/0x50f5474724e0ee42d9a4e711ccfb275809fd6d4a#writeContract) on etherscan, connect your Ledger via metamask ("Connect on web3" button) and use the transferFrom function to send the NFT to another EOA (use safeTransferFrom is you'd rather send it to another contract)

Comment: Thank you for your clear and helpful guidance. I did as you recommended and it worked.

Comment: Good to hear! Don’t forget tagging the answer as accepted;)