# Wrong Ethereum Address

Tags: transactions

I accidentally sent NFT to the ERC20 address on my ledger that doesn't support the transfer; the wallet shows no transaction. Can I reclaim my NFT?

0x054138a3d3c7cc8925b163eafcdd60612b63425eb7e841034ed735a19a9bdc72

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transfer Mistake between ERC20 vs ERC721](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/114007/transfer-mistake-between-erc20-vs-erc721)

Comment: Thanks, will give it a go. By the sounds of things the NFT is recoverable.  I made the transfer to ledger with my coinbase wallet but I presume I can go back and connect to ledger with my metamask ?